# Change dtype of dataframe automatically after applying some operations

Tags: python, pandas

```
txt = '''A B C 
1Â 2Â abcÂ
2Â 5Â defÂ'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep = '\s{1,}')
```

So this is a dataframe:

```
    A   B   C
0   1Â  2Â  abcÂ
1   2Â  5Â  defÂ
```

now df.dtypes gives:

```
A    object
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

After removing special character `Â`.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('Â'))
```

I want to change the `dtypes` of each column appropriately.

I've used  `df.infer_dtype().dtypes` but it still gives `object dtype`. 
I've also used `pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df)` but it gives `string`, but I want `dtypes` for each columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the dataframe `.astype()` method to change the `dtypes`. Use a `dict` to target specific columns and their intended types.

```
import numpy as np

# Create data frame and clean data...

types = {'A': np.int64, 'B': np.int64, 'C': np.str}
df = df.astype(types)

df.dtypes

A     int64
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object
```

**EDIT:** If I understand you correctly, you want the dtypes of data frame after you've cleaned it.  In that case, you can do the following:

```
# Implicitly convert numeric types; see the 'convert_objects'
# documentation for other supported types
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

df.apply(pd.api.types.infer_dtype)

A    integer
B    integer
C     string
dtype: object
```

Or, for a dict:

```
dict(df.apply(pd.api.types.infer_dtype))

{'A': 'integer', 'B': 'integer', 'C': 'string'}
```

Note: I'm using pandas 0.23.3.

**EDIT 2:** Per your request here is the full code I'm using. I've simplified it as well, so that no inference is necessary.

```
from io import StringIO
txt = '''A B C 
1Â 2Â abcÂ
2Â 5Â defÂ'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep = '\s{1,}', engine='python')
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('Â'))

df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

df.dtypes

A     int64
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Even though that works, I believe OP wants exactly to NOT manually set the types..

Comment: I just want to get the `types` dictionary without hardcoding, as there are 100s of columns. @RafaelC any help?

Comment: @krishna Please see revised answer.

Comment: @T.Ray in my case it is giving `string` for all column. I'm using pandas 0.22.0

Comment: @krishna It looks like you'll need to convert some of the string types first. See `convert_objects` docs for other supported types (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html).

Comment: @krishna In case it wasn't clear, I revised the answer to show how `convert_objects` works.

Comment: @sorry for bothering you. I've upgraded my pandas version to yours but `dict(df.apply(pd.api.types.infer_dtype))` is still giving for all columns.

Comment: Are you using convert_objects beforehand?

Comment: no i'm not using. can you just post the complete code that you're trying either in answer or on pastebin.I'll take care of the rest.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. See Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because your `1` and `2` are actually `"1"` and `"2"`. So pandas just infers you have columns of strings because, well, they are strings. They are strings because pandas inferred `1Â` to be a string, and when you strip the `Â` out, you are left with the str `"1"`

What you can do instead is to parse your data beforehand, and just create the data frame with a cleaned data.

For example

```
def clean(txt):
    return txt.read().replace('Â', '')
```

Now

```
pd.read_table(StringIO(clean(txt)), delim_whitespace=True).dtypes
```

yields

```
A     int64
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: It works in this case. But I want to change type after reading the dataframe and cleaning in general case. Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after stripping:  `df = df._convert(numeric=True)`